# Returning JSON response for Spring MVC Post request

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, java-7, plupload

I have the below controller method which is uploading files to my server. I would like to return JSON for Plupload's status. However the response seems to be sent back as a dispatch rather than a json @ResponseBody.  Any Ideas?

```
    private static final String RESP_SUCCESS = "{\"jsonrpc\" : \"2.0\", \"result\" : \"success\", \"id\" : \"id\"}";
    private static final String RESP_ERROR = "{\"jsonrpc\" : \"2.0\", \"error\" : {\"code\": 101, \"message\": \"Failed to upload file.\"}, \"id\" : \"id\"}";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadItem(@RequestBody MultipartFile file,
                             @RequestParam String name,
                             @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int chunks,
                             @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int chunk) {
        Media media = new Media();
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get("/Users/username/Desktop/Test", file.getOriginalFilename());
            media.setContentType(file.getContentType());
            media.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            media.setFileSize(file.getSize());
            media.setFilePath(path.toString());
            if (media.getContentType().contains("image")) {
                Image image = new Image();
                image.setImagePath(path.toString());
                imageDao.save(image);
            }
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Files.write(path, bytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
            mediaDao.save(media);
            return RESP_SUCCESS;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return RESP_ERROR;
    }
}
```

Throws the following error:

```
WARN - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : "success", "id" : "id"}] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cr'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your method should be annotated with @ResponseBody.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public  String uploadItem(@RequestBody MultipartFile file,
                             @RequestParam String name,
                             @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int chunks,
                             @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "-1")
```

This is how Spring checks for Json conversion:

- Jackson library is existed in the project classpath
- The mvc:annotation-driven is enabled
- Return method annotated with @ResponseBody

Spring will handle the JSON conversion automatically.

Comment: I edited your answer to the method I used that ended up fixing it since your's was close enough to get me there.   Thank you!

Comment: Syntax isn't correct, please don't edit an answer suggesting a completely wrong syntax from what the text says ("return type should be @ResponseBody") as it no longer makes sense.

Comment: @ThomasW An annotation usage cannot be return type. The return type is `String`. The method is annotated with `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: @ThomasW Or are you simply saying their wording is wrong?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis -- read the wording of Juned's answer (which is distinctly different from what helpful people have "fixed" the code to be). "I think your method return type should be `@ResponseBody` and not String." His original answer included incorrect code to that effect. Juned incorrectly believes `@ResponseBody` is a valid return-type, which it is not.

Comment: I agree the return type cannot be @ResponseBody, it should be String only. I am not sure what I was thinking when I put in that answer. Hope now the code and description are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Method must have a return type of String, which is separate from the annotation (that the result is to be used as the reponse body).

@ResponseBody is not a return type, or a type at all! It is an annotation.

Textual content & syntax proposed in the previous answer is grossly wrong, though I give it credit in other respects.

My suggestion:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public String uploadItem(@RequestBody MultipartFile file,
                         @RequestParam String name,
                         @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int chunks,
                         @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "-1")
```

Comment: `@ResponseBody public String uploadItem(..)` is equivalent to `public @ResponseBody String uploadItem(..)`. The Java syntax allows both.

Comment: `@ResponseBody` is an annotation, not a type -- thus can't possibly be the return-type of a method. For this reason Juned's answer is unambiguously wrong. But thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis for info on annotating return-type of a method, being equivalent to annotating the method itself.